# Mysql query for month to date, last month and previous month

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a post_meta database which contains the following fields:
meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value

I have created a view in PhpMyAdmin to isolate only those records with specific text to bring up a list of clients and appointment times. Each record is unique so that for a client with several appointments they would have the same name, but different time and ID. Name and time are  contained in the meta_value column. [Column view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKYGn.png)

Here is an example:

```
postID | appt_date  |   firstname    | lastname
-----------------------------------------------
2106   | 1427698800 |   Sam          | Snead
2107   | 1428649200 |   John         | Miller
2108   | 1428476400 |   Sam          | Snead
```

My challenge is pulling both the number of appointments for the month to date, last month (e.g. Sept) and previous month ( e.g. Aug), as well as the total unique clients for the month. I am going to graph this so that the result is a column and line graph with Aug clients (column) and Aug appointments (line), sim for Sept. The MTD would be prev month plus whatever new clients and appointments so far in the month.

I not had much luck because the date is in Unix format and the month to date (which of course varies based on the day of the month). Additionally the clients show up multiple times (some of them have had 50 appointments) so selecting them only once is a challenge.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Some hints.. you can use FROM_UNIXTIME to generate a valid DATETIME like so `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1427698800) ` returns `2015-03-30 09:00:00` Now you can use MONTHNAME function to return the month like so `SELECT MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(1427698800))` returns 'March'... good luck with this information

Answer (score 0):

You can get this month and last month using some date() (on php side):

```
$this_month = date("Y-m-d");
$last_day_this_month = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($this_month));
$first_day_this_month = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($this_month));
$next_month = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($last_day_this_month." + 5 days"));
$last_month = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($first_day_this_month." - 5 days"));
```

Being in unix time just use date on the unix time and you will get the formatted time.

The rest is just doing some count on or group by clauses in the SQL part.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you seem to want this :

you want the total number of appointments client A had in september, the same for august. Do i get that right ?

In that case you will need to figure out the right date/time to look at in your query you can do this by making use of an epoch converter such as (https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

When you found the correct epochs you can use those in your where i.e :

```
where appt_date  < (highest epoch last day of month with time 00:00) and 
appt_date  > (last day of previous month time 00:00)
```

That isolates the time between the first and last day of the month you want to have.

For your second problem : as well as the total unique clients for the month. I would urge you to look at how to use the distinct or group by functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function to convert the unix timestamp to a date, and then use the `MONTH()` function to get the month number. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_appointments, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(appt_date)) as number_month 
    FROM {your_view} 
    GROUP BY number_month
```

will give you the total number of appointments per month.

Comment: Thanks Jose! I have found that I need to clarify in this case. Group by number_month gives a listing of the month 1-12 and the proportionate number of appointments.  What I realize is that it is any 12 month period and I want to go back the three. What I tried was this - SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_appointments, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`meta_value`)) as number_month 
    FROM acquity_fields 
    GROUP BY number_month DESC  and I assume that the month numbers correspond to the Names of the months.

Comment: Yes, the number of the month correspond to the name. 1 => January, 2 => February and so on. What else do you need?

Comment: Good, when I used monthname(from_unixtime('meta_value)) instead of month; it displays the months in alphabetical order instead of corresponding to the numbers. Does this change the UNIX time?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's exactly the same thing.